# Print double data type with a precision upto 4 decimal places - Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to use the armadillo library in c++ to do the following.

Whenever I print out a matrix (`arma::mat`), it is always printed in the following form:-

```
1.0594e+03   1.0439e+04   0.3425e+04
1.0232e+03  12.0319e+04   0.1225e+04
11.5044e+03   1.231e+04   0.3424e+04
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to remove the `e+04` and actually printing out the whole numbers like:-

```
 1059.4   1043.9  3425.0
1023.23 120319.0  1225.0
11504.4   1231.0  3424.0
```

Comment: can you please provide a small sample code where you create a matrix and print it out, and what the rules for calculating precision are? You have two decimal places on one number and one decimal place on all others in your expected output. Also please provide a link to the armadillo documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of googeling takes me to http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#raw_print which says:

> Similar to the .print() member function, with the difference that no formatting of the output is done; the stream's parameters such as precision, cell width, etc. can be set manually

And shows this example:

```
mat A = randu<mat>(5,5);

cout.precision(11);
cout.setf(ios::fixed);

A.raw_print(cout, "A:");
```

If that is what you are looking for, then you can study further here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags to see other formatting parameters you can set.